# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined, This is an error which I am getting in my code

Tags: javascript

```js
const langProject = document.createElement('ul');
langProject.classList.add('lang-project');
projectCardContent.appendChild(langProject);
const btn = document.createElement('li');
btn.projectTechnologies.forEach((btnTech) => {
    const btn = document.createElement('li');
    btn.innerText = project.projectTechnologies;
    projectTechnologies.appendChild(techItem);
```

I have included a sample of my code which is throwing the error on the title. I am quite a newbie at this and i was just following a tutorial, why is the forEach not defined?

Comment: What do you expect `btn.projectTechnologies` to be?

Comment: i want it to show the list of technologies used using javascript

Comment: But why would `btn.projectTechnologies` return that?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?